# In STM32F407 microcontroller (or if not known, general trends in computers), do pins in GPIO ports interface EXTI lines via multiplexers?

Tags: microcontroller, gpio-external-interrupt

I've studied and worked with STM32F407 during the spring, and I was wondering about the rationale behind how it organizes external interrupts. To understand this, it would be beneficial if I could understand how it works at the hardware level, how signals from pins are wired to EXTI interrupt lines. I assume multiplexers are used, and that is what I want to ask about.

I assume there are general trends across how microcontrollers or computers solve external interrupts, so answers *do not have to specifically be about STM32F407* (if schematics for it happen to be hard to find), but I'll use it as a reference in my question.

The EXTI system has 16 interrupt lines, EXTI0 to EXTI 15, and each can interface the corresponding pin in any of the GPIO ports, of which there are roughly 10 (9 or 11 depending on exact version of STM32F4**), I will use 10 here. So each EXTI line has to be able to select one of 10 signals. I would assume it uses a multiplexer with 10 inputs and one output for that.

The configuration for what GPIO port an EXTI line should use, is done in SYSCFG in 4 bit registers, I assume these registers are used as selection input to the multiplexers.

What I want to ask is, is 16 multiplexers likely used for the 10 GPIO ports to route the pin from the desired port to the EXTI line?

#### Follow-up question if anyone is interested

If yes, is the reason they only allow the corresponding pin for an EXTI line, instead of any pin to any EXTI line, that the latter would require multiplexers with 160 inputs instead of 10, and 8 bit selection inputs, and that this is a lot of added parts?

Or is there some other rationale for why they use the pin_x to line_x mapping?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? If you want a generic explanation, I'm afraid that the question is too broad. If you want a specific answer for the STM32F407, the reference manual (you read it, didn't you?) has a lot to say. In the latter case, why did the RM not help you, what specific detail is left open? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I think I cover that in question already. Datasheets and reference manual typically cover absolute minimum user needs to know, the rest is proprietary. If I had a schematic I would not have asked here. Is that not well know, why would I have to clarify it? I have no experience with how GPIO pins may interface EXTI, so, it is reasonable to ask on a hardware Q&A where people may have experience with it. And, general solutions usually exist and trends exist. I can't really see a good way to do it besides multiplexers but maybe there is, and someone with experience would know that straight away.

Comment: What makes you think that chip designers follow trends? In these days there is a lot of abstract hardware description, which separates the designer from the final result. When is a multiplexer a multiplexer for you? If the programming model of the data sheet shows it? If you could spot transistors in the silicon, building gates that resemble the typical school multiplexer? I would not expect that. And why is it important for you to know whether there are multiplexers or not? The relevant thing is the programming model of the specific microcontroller.

Comment: my impression is that in anything engineered, ever, in the history of mankind, there are trends. You have already asked why I did not look at the RM, while anyone knows it does not cover proprietary detail. A multiplexer is a multiplexer when you route one of multiple signals to an output, this is also not something I should need to clarify, is it?

Comment: So I'm still do not know what you want. Please clarify **in** the question. Would you like to see a statistic chart, which percentage of microcontrollers use what programming model? For example, providing a control register with one-out-of-n selection, in contrast to binary coded selection? You are right, this is a Q&A site. But your question should be clear enough to be answerable. BTW, which range of chips are microcontrollers for you? Any device from 4-bitters to high-end ARM SoC?

Comment: and why is knowing the schematic important for me, I am interested in how it works. why is that even a question? this Q&A was historically "chiphacker" but why is "chiphacking" important if you can just stay in Windows user space?

Comment: the question is pretty clear, I will automove discussion to chat where it can be continued

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147624/discussion-between-bipedaljoe-and-the-busybee).

Comment: @thebusybee You were right it was in the reference manual. I apologize for missing that, have mostly used datasheets for the chip before and they are more shallow so I assumed the RM (although I had used it a bit) would not go into that much detail. Thanks for solving the question for me, and sorry for not listening.

Comment: Why close the question? That is nonsensical. The question does focus on one problem. My answer answers that one problem. The question also suggests that if the answer to that one problem was hard to acquire, then somewhat broader answers are accepted too. The question is answered so clearly it was answerable. Why I asked if multiplexers were used, I assumed there may be some other way to do it, that I did not consider, so I asked.

Comment: @BipedalJoe - If you disagree with closure of a question, the process is [here](/help/reopen-questions). I have left your one allowed comment - I don't think it's constructive enough to help you, but (within the limits of the CoC) it's allowed. You are not allowed to to use vulgar language (so 1 comment deleted), nor is this the correct place to criticise standard SE model about VTC (so another comment deleted). If you want to petition to change SE policy, write a post on Meta.SE. If you want to *politely* question the closure of your question, ask on our Meta. Do *not* reply here. TY

Answer (score 1):

As @thebusybee suggested in a comment, I should read the reference manual. I dismissed that it was covered there, but then double checked and it actually was. On page 382 and section 12.2.5: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0090-stm32f405415-stm32f407417-stm32f427437-and-stm32f429439-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf.

My assumption about multiplexers and such was right.

In the block diagram below from the manual, it shows the pins being routed to multiplexers.

[image]

This does not directly answer what the rationale is to choose that design (only one pin X from any GPIO allowed to be used for external interrupt). If anyone knows, I am interested. For now, I'll assume that it is to cut down on parts (multiplexers input decreased by 16x and selection bit inputs by 2x) unless I find a better explanation.